# SAPUI 5 add Button Press Event

Tags: button, sapui5

I would like to know how we can write buttion press event in controller.
i.e. if the condition is satisfied, button is pressed.

this.getView().byId("idHeadBtn").press

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I hope that I understand you correctly. You want to add a button handling for a particular button right? If so, you could do this:

```js
var btn = this.getView().byId("idHeadBtn"); //or sap.ui.getCore().byId("idHeadBtn");
btn.attachPress(/*pressHandler*/);
```

For more information you could double check it: https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Button/methods/attachPress